why does not insert the (temp->rlink)->llink (circular double linked list)
I want to know why (*dlist)->llink is not x(lptint error) when i write &(temp->rlink) instead &x
void lprintList(listPointer dlist) {
    listPointer temp = (listPointer)malloc(sizeof(*temp)); // sizeof(Node)
    temp = dlist;
    temp = temp->llink;
    while (temp != dlist) {
        printf("[%d]", temp->item);
        temp = temp->llink;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void searchInsertList(listPointer* dlist, element item) {
    listPointer temp = (listPointer)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp = *dlist;
    temp = temp->llink;
    while (temp != *dlist && item < temp->item) {
        temp = temp->llink;
    }
    listPointer x = temp->rlink;
    insertList(&x, item);           <------------------
}

void insertList(listPointer* dlist, element item) {
    listPointer x = (listPointer)malloc(sizeof(*x));
    x->item = item;
    x->rlink = *dlist;
    x->llink = (*dlist)->llink;
    (*dlist)->llink->rlink = x;
    (*dlist)->llink = x;        <-------------------
}

insertList(&(temp->rlink), item);

then
(*dlist)->llink = x;

I don't know why llink of (*dlist) is not x

Honestly, please do not typedef pointers! Thats just information hiding with absolutely no benefit.

First thing I notice is a memory leak: : temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); temp = dlist; – you lose the one and only pointer to the just malloced memory. How would you ever want to get access to again? Why would you malloc at all? You just want to iterate, don't you?

Same again in second function – only in third one you really want to malloc, only there you really want to create a new node.

Why do you need a pointer to pointer at all in insertList? You are not assigning anything to *dlist anyway.

You should produce a [mre]. How do you test? It might be (or not) that you are simply mixing up variables (equally named variables, including parameters, of different functions are distinct variables, albeit sharing a name).

Code does what I assume you intend to do, see godbolt (just dropped the double pointer indirection there, which has no influence, though) – apart from that you maybe did not want to insert/print in descending order...

Thank you so much for your advice on grammar and questions. I'll apply what you said and code it.

post a complete piece of code. helps others help you and help others

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
